# What is the equivalent in metal of glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)?

Tags: objective-c, metal, metalkit

What is the equivalent in metal of `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`? The Depth Test is a per-sample processing operation performed after the Fragment Shader (and sometimes before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a depth-stencil state object created from a descriptor whose `depthCompareFunction` is not `MTLCompareFunctionAlways`.